# Suppress console output when switching runlevels

Tags: tty, init, runlevel

Is there any way to silence the output that occurs on TTY1 when switching runlevels?

I'm talking about the output like in the following image:
[image]

I have a simple UI that may be running on TTY1 when the runlevel is changed and it corrupts the curses output, which looks very ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not: those messages are written to the *console*, and your `TTY1` is just one of the virtual consoles that happen to be using it.

The service stop/start messages are not written by a child process of your command (otherwise you could redirect them to `/dev/null`).

On the other hand, you can suppress some other types of messages written to the console (kernel messages, as mentioned in [How do I disable messages or logging from printing on the console/virtual terminals?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97256/how-do-i-disable-messages-or-logging-from-printing-on-the-console-virtual-termin)).

But in a quick check of CentOS 7, neither redirecting the output of `init` nor using `dmesg -n 1` affects messages sent going from runlevel 5 to 3.  The command-shell does get logged out (which would be expected for your program as well).